# Azure Database for PostgreSQL: "InvalidInputs" error restoring an LTR backup from Azure Backup Vault

Tags: database-restore, azure-postgresql, azure-backup-vault

I am trying to restore an long-term retention (LTR) Azure Database for PostgreSQL database backup using Azure Backup Vault as described in these articles:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-database-postgresql (backup configuration steps)
- https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/9/91990314-33bd-4eaa-a084-d1f7e6175ee1/AzBkpPostgres_ManualPermissions.docx (indirectly linked by the above article)

The LTR backups are completing without issues, however, restoring them to the Azure Database for PostgreSQL resource leads to an "InvalidInputs" error:

[image]

With this in the Activity Log:

```json
    "properties": {
        "statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"InvalidInputs\",\"message\":\"\",\"additionalInfo\":[{\"type\":\"UserFacingError\",\"info\":{\"message\":\"\",\"recommendedAction\":[\"\"],\"code\":\"InvalidInputs\",\"target\":\"\",\"isRetryable\":false,\"isUserError\":false,\"properties\":{\"ActivityId\":\"a7a2867e-8889-41c4-a5cf-37fd1394d3d6-Ibz\"}}}]}]}}",
        "eventCategory": "Administrative",
        "entity": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/poc-rg/providers/Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/XXXXXXXXXXpoc-psql-bv-2/backupInstances/XXXXXXXXXXpoc-psql-2-backup_restore_test_2",
        "message": "Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/backupInstances/ValidateRestore/action",
        "hierarchy": "30ff29b8-a165-42a0-a594-f726229a5954"
    },
```

Restoring to an Azure Storage Account leads to this error:

[image]

```json
    "properties": {
        "statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"SMAWTeeInternalError\",\"message\":\"Microsoft Azure Backup encountered an internal error.\",\"additionalInfo\":[{\"type\":\"UserFacingError\",\"info\":{\"message\":\"Microsoft Azure Backup encountered an internal error.\",\"recommendedAction\":[\"Wait for a few minutes and then try the operation again. If the issue persists, please contact Microsoft support.\"],\"code\":\"SMAWTeeInternalError\",\"target\":\"\",\"isRetryable\":false,\"isUserError\":false,\"properties\":{\"ActivityId\":\"a7a2867e-8889-41c4-a5cf-37fd1394d3dd-Ibz\"}}}]}]}}",
        "eventCategory": "Administrative",
        "entity": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/poc-rg/providers/Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/XXXXXXXXXXpoc-psql-bv-2/backupInstances/XXXXXXXXXXpoc-psql-2-backup_restore_test_2",
        "message": "Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/backupInstances/ValidateRestore/action",
        "hierarchy": "30ff29b8-a165-42a0-a594-f726229a5954"
    },
```

I have tried with both Azure Database for PostgreSQL versions 10 and 11. The `azure_backup` role is granted the following permissions:

```sql
ALTER USER azure_backup WITH CREATEDB;
GRANT azure_pg_admin TO azure_backup;
```

Any insight or help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue when trying to restore into a storage account as a file. Did you find the cause?

Comment: Even after giving the backup vault contributor permissions as described in the docs it does not work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-database-postgresql?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support#troubleshooting

Comment: We were not able to determine the cause and simply labelled the restore capabilities (to both a new database and to a Storage Account) as a preview feature limitation. We moved on to other things for now.

Comment: I opened a support ticket with Azure for this issue and let you know if I get some good news.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this issue in the September update of 2021. Please re-try with the latest version.